# R - Ordering bar graph by median revenue

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently have a table with the following :

```
promo   ad    med_revenue
 No   Medium    31.92       
 No   Small     33.12       
 Yes  Medium    38.25       
 Yes  Small     32.50
```

```
gm_ab %>% 
  group_by(promo, ad) %>%
  summarize(median_revenue = median(revenue)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = reorder(promo, -median_revenue), 
                       y = median_revenue, 
                       fill = ad)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Adding the graph]

Question: How can I separate the bars, so I can have four different X - variables where it displays them in order by median price? For example: *no promo-small ad* , *yes promo-medium ad*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a new variable of the interaction between `promo` and `ad` using `str_c`:

```
df <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~promo,      ~ad, ~med_revenue,
      "No", "Medium",        31.92,
      "No",  "Small",        33.12,
     "Yes", "Medium",        38.25,
     "Yes",  "Small",         32.5
  )

df %>% 
  mutate(promo_ad = str_c(promo, ad, sep = " - ")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(promo_ad, -med_revenue), y = med_revenue, fill = ad)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```